# How to interpret result of InverseFourier?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Consider this simple example:

```
data=Table[(Cos[y*Pi/8]),{x,1,16},{y,1,16}];
Chop[InverseFourier[data,FourierParameters->{1, -1}]]
```

The array I get is all zeros except for two elements. All the non-zero elements are where I expect them, but the non-zero values are 0.46194+0.191342 * I, 0.46194-0.191342 * I. Why do we get those values? I changed the Cos to Sin and the non-zero parts still have a real part and complex part.

Comment: Up to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourier.html?q=InverseFourier), `InverseFourier` of a real-valued matrix may not be a real -valued matrix.

Answer (score 2):

As your data does not depend on x, we may, to simplify, only consider the the y- dependence. Note that the forward and inverse Fourier transform only differ in the sign of the frequency and eventually in a scale factor. Therefore, the first row of your transformed matrix belongs to y-frequencies with x-frequency equal to zero. And we need only look at the data of this first row:

```
d= {0, 0.46194 - 0.191342 I, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
 0.46194 + 0.191342 I}
```

The first element corresponds to the DC part, that is the constant part. The second and the last element belong to the positive and negative frequency of Pi/8 (the lowest frequency contained in the data, The third and second  last element would correspond to twice this frequency e.t.c.). We can show this by explicitly calculating function values from the base functions: Exp[+/- I frequency y] like:

```
freq = Pi/8;
f[y_] = (0.46193976625564337` - 
      0.19134171618254486` I) Exp[+I freq y ] + (0.46193976625564337` \
+ 0.19134171618254486` I) Exp[- I freq y];
Table[f[y], {y, 0, 15}] // Chop
(* {0.92388, 1., 0.92388, 0.707107, 0.382683, 0, -0.382683, -0.707107, \
-0.92388, -1., -0.92388, -0.707107, -0.382683, 0, 0.382683, 0.707107} *)
```

We may compare this to the first row of the original data:

```
data[[1]]

(* {0.92388, 0.707107, 0.382683, 0., -0.382683, -0.707107, -0.92388, \
-1., -0.92388, -0.707107, -0.382683, 0., 0.382683, 0.707107, 0.92388, \
1.} *)
```

It is now obvious that the above frequencies creates the data.

Note also, because the original data is real, the contributions from the pos./neg. frequencies must be conjugate complex, so that the imaginary parts cancel.

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseFourier.html?q=InverseFourier) before having answered? There is an example of complex values for real-valued input there.

Comment: @Daniel Huber, You helped me figure out where my mistake was. I posted my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler example would have been:

```
data=Table[(Cos[y*Pi/8]),{x,0,15},{y,0,15}];
```

Notice:

```
Cos[Pi/8]Cos[n*Pi/8]-Sin[Pi/8]Sin[n*Pi/8]==Cos[(n+1)Pi/8]
(* True *)
```

So the data in the question is equivalent to:

```
data=Table[Cos[Pi/8]Cos[x*Pi/8]-Sin[Pi/8]Sin[x*Pi/8],{x,0,15},{y,0,15}];
```

Then we do the InverseFourier using:

```
inverseTransform=Chop[InverseFourier[data,FourierParameters->{1,-1}]]
```

and the non-zero parts of this inverseTransform are:

```
{(Cos[Pi/8]-Sin[Pi/8]I)/2,(Cos[Pi/8]+Sin[Pi/8]I)/2}
```